# PokeAPI: Is there a way to request normalized data instead of nested json?

Tags: pokeapi

I've been using the PokeAPI for testing different UI libraries, and there are cases where the heavily nested JSON it returns is kind of annoying. Is there any way to get an endpoint to return canonical resource urls instead of eagerly loaded entity data? I scoured the API docs and can't find any answers.

Comment: No, sorry, there isn't. The API is served the way we do, we don't offer any alternatives.

Comment: We had a GraphQL fork that might be what you're looking for.